# Extjs - How to use ComponentQuery to find several similar components

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

In my application, I have several views that have the same buttons on the toolbar. In the contraoller, I would like to use one ComponentQuery only to listen to the click event on all similar buttons.

My view 1 is as follows:

```
alias: 'widget.view-type1',
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [{
        text: 'Add',
        itemId: 'add'
    }
```

In my controller, instead of calling

```
init: function(){
    this.control({
        'view-type1 #add, view-type2 #add, view-type3 #add, view-type4 #add': {click: this.onButtonAdd},
```

I'd like something like

```
init: function(){
    this.control({
        'view-generic #add': {click: this.onButtonAdd},
```

I should be able to add a config property to my view 1, like:

```
secondaryAlias: 'widget.view-generic',
```

But this does not exist.

My question is, how to declare those views in such a way, that I can target them all together with a simple ComponentQuery. I hope this explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property for every of your classes like this:

```
mySecondaryAlias: 'view-generic',
```

And then use search by property:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[mySecondaryAlias=view-generic] #add')
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. Your query will find the button on `view-type1`-view, but it will not find the same button on the three other similar views.

Comment: Corrected that. Also please note that `#add` is in a toolbar and you say that the query finds it, but I didn't try it.